# Twitter background won't tile

Tags: twitter

I have uploaded an image for the background onto my profile. It uploads and displays correctly as long as I don't check tile background. I want the image to tile, when I click on tile background it previews correctly. When I hit save changes it tiles clouds, my image is no longer there.

I have tried IE, Chrome, and Firefox, two computers one running Windows 8 the other Vista. It seems to be a know issue as the twitter forums are overrun with people complaining about it. Any ideas?

I am looking for a work around, or maybe the picture has to be a certain size or something.

Answer (score -1):

Go to [Themeleon](http://www.colourlovers.com/themeleon/twitter) and upload your picture and tile. Worked for me.

Comment: I suggest giving a little more info, such as a step by step or some images displaying how to do this.